# Is there any chance KeyChain value is unavailable in applicationWillEnterForeground in iOS?

Tags: ios, sskeychain

When opening the app from background i am calling one api, i need to send user mobile number in that api, mobile number is stored in KeyChain. Sometime in backend they are not getting mobile number. But i am not able to reproduce the issue.

*so i want to know is there any chance KeyChain is unavailable applicationWillEnterForeground?*

I am using below code for access mobileNumber in keyChain

```
//Storing   
 SSKeychainQuery *query = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
 query.service = serviceName;
 query.account = account;
 query.password = mobileNumber;


//Getting password
SSKeychainQuery *query = [[SSKeychainQuery alloc] init];
query.service = serviceName;
query.account = account;
[query fetch:error];
NSString *mobileNUmber =  query.password;
```

We are using Objective-C language..

Comment: can you give us some sample code how you are storing and retrieving data from UserDefaults?

Comment: can you provide more info? when do you save mobile number to UserDefaults? Are you using Swift or Objective-C, because in Swift 2 and lower, or in Objective-C you need to call synchronize() to make sure it saves to persistent storage before retrieve it

Comment: Thanks for ur quick Reply..now only i came to know we are not using UserDefaults. we are using Keychain for storing Mobile Number. Now i will edit my question..